# Is there a way to utilize polars mapping to make this code more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, python-polars

I have some polars code that functionally can do what I want, but I feel it is an inefficient implementation at best. I feel that there must be some way to achieve the same result with `.map()`, but I can't figure out how. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Specifically, my data are organized as follows: Each column is a location, and each row is a datetime. What I'm trying to do is calculate the maximum count of consecutive non-zero values (which I converted to Booleans because I don't need the magnitude of the value, I just need to know if the value is zero or not). Example data and example expected output below:

**Example Dummy Data**

| Date | Location 1 | Location 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-23 00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 01-01-23 01:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 01-01-23 02:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 01-01-23 03:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 01-01-23 04:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 01-01-23 05:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 01-01-23 06:00 | 1 | 0 |

**Expected Output**:

| Location | Maximum Cumulative Count |
| --- | --- |
| Location 1 | 3 |
| Location 2 | 5 |

Below is the code I have that is *functional*, but feels like it can be improved my someone smarter and more well-versed in polars than I am.

```
for col in pivoted_df.drop("Date").columns:
    xy_cont_df_a = (
        pivoted_df.select(pl.col(col))
        .with_columns(
            pl.when(
                pl.col(col).cast(pl.Boolean)
                & pl.col(col)
                .cast(pl.Boolean)
                .shift_and_fill(-1, False)
                .is_not()
            ).then(
                pl.count().over(
                    (
                        pl.col(col).cast(pl.Boolean)
                        != pl.col(col).cast(pl.Boolean).shift()
                    ).cumsum()
                )
            )
        )
        .max()
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Update:** Polars `0.18.7` added [`.rle()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle.html) and [`.rle_id()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html) which simplify these types of tasks.

```
df.select(
   pl.col('Location 1', 'Location 2').rle()
     .struct['lengths'].max().keep_name()
)
```

```
shape: (1, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ Location 1 ┆ Location 2 │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ i64        ┆ i64        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 3          ┆ 5          │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

With unpivoted data:

```
df.groupby('Location').agg(
   pl.col('Value').rle().struct['lengths'].max()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ Location   ┆ Value │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str        ┆ i32   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ Location 2 ┆ 5     │
│ Location 1 ┆ 3     │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thank you, and you are correct about the pivot. The original dataset is the unpivoted form of the dummy data provided. One column for dates, one column for locations, and one column for values. Is there a way to accomplish the same end result without first pivoting?

Comment: @bdshoener There are a few ways you could do it, I've added one possible approach.

Comment: Wow! Here I am thinking I am fairly knowledgeable on data manipulation, and your answer blows anything I can do out of the water. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @bdshoener If you do `df.select(pl.struct(["Location", consecutive]).value_counts())` it's essentially doing that, then extracting the max count per location. It's possible there is a simpler way, that's just how I parsed it.